# Replace single quotes

Tags: apex, string, replaceall

I need to replace single quotes. However, I cannot use the `"`
double quote character. Therefore, I cannot do something like this:

```java
String s = "Hello 'thanks' bye";
    s = s.replaceAll("'", "\\'");
System.out.println(s);
    // Hello \'thanks\' bye
```

I need to replace the single quotes in `str` with `\'`, that is, when I print `str` I should get an output of `Hello \'thanks\' bye`. Without using double quotes, how do I achieve this with Apex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a built-in method [`String.escapeSingleQuotes()`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) that handles this need nicely. From the documentation, an example:

```
String s = '\'Hello Jason\'';
system.debug(s); // Outputs 'Hello Jason'
String escapedStr = String.escapeSingleQuotes(s);
// Outputs \'Hello Jason\'
system.debug(escapedStr); 
// Escapes the string \\\' to string \'
system.assertEquals('\\\'Hello Jason\\\'', escapedStr);
```

Bear in mind that when writing literal strings in Apex you can include single quotes by escaping them with a backslash `\`, and to include a literal backslash you must escape it too. That's why the last line has `'\\\'Hello Jason\\\''`.

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for!  Thank you!